# How can I Update Spreadsheet cell value directly from Html Page using appscript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-api, sourceforge-appscript

I have a Planning sheet with huge data. For every row will have 200+ columns (cells). I wanted to change the cell value from html page using appscript.

How can we change the cell value directly from Html Table view.

Please help.

Regards
RS

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared a sample of the data as well as the code that generates the HTML, from what I understand you want to do a kind of CRUD using Google Apps Script, right?

Comment: You can use google.script.run.  Please try doing you own code before asking us.

Comment: Yes Emel looking for CRUD with spreadsheet edit with huge edit fields.

Comment: As @Cooper mentioned, you can retrieve the elements inside a SpreadSheet into a HTML. After that, you should follow the common steps to build a CRUD. You can follow this [guide](https://gist.github.com/Tito0269/2014c7001c89ed596171baea229d3363) on how to build a CRUD inside Apps Script

Answer (score 1):

## Update value of cell in Spreadsheet from HTML page

```
function updatecellvaluefromhtmlpage() {
  let html = '<form><input type="text" name="thisvalue" size="25" placeholder = "Enter Value" /><br /><input type="button" value="Click to change value of A1 in Sheet1" onClick="google.script.run.changeValueOfA1(this.parentNode);" />'
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html),'Change Value Sheet1A1');
}

function changeValueOfA1(obj) {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sh.getRange('A1').setValue(obj.thisvalue)
}
```

[htmlservice](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service)

[show modeless](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html#showModelessDialog(Object,String))

[google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

**Html Dialog:**

[image]

**Changed Cell:**

[image]